# How to get the $_FILES array data as it is after form submission in following scenario?

Tags: php, forms, file, hidden-field

I've a form with too many fields. One of these fields is as follows:

```
<form action="go_to_preview.php" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="equip_image" id="equip_image">
</form>
```

Now the purpose of file `go_to_preview.php` is to show the data filled in by user in the form of labels. All the filled in data are also contained in hidden fields. If user finds whatever he/she has filled in is perfect then user clicks the submit button present on file `go_to_preview.php`. As soon as user clicks on submit button I'll add the data I received through `$_POST` to the database. 
Now my issue is along with `$_POST`(which is an array of data present into hidden fields) I want the data from `$_FILES` as it is. How should I achieve this? Can someone please help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you submit your form, both the $_POST and $_FILES data are sent as seperate arrays, you can see this by going to go_to_preview.php and using `var_dump($_FILES)` and `var_dump($_POST)`, you should see both have the correct contents :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach would be sessions:

```
//go_to_preview.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['FILES'] = $_FILES;

//final.php
session_start();
$files_var = $_SESSION['FILES'];
//use $files_var
unset($_SESSION['FILES']);
```

Comment: But after submission of a form for last time when I insert the data into database the $_FILES should get removed from sessions. How should I do it?

Comment: Edited: Use `unset()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you tell me if I don't use sessions and store the $_FILES data into a hidden field. Will it work?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same.  I use session for both instead of hidden fields.  Seems easier to say `$_SESSION['fields'] = $_POST` than to create a bunch of hidden fields.

Comment: I tried storing $_FILES array data into hidden field but I'm getting blank hidden field. why?

Comment: You can't store the array unless you serialize it or store each element in it's own hidden field.  That's why I suggested sessions ;-)

Comment: Let's come to chat room. add me to your room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60919/discussion-between-user2839497-and-abracadaver).

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly you are asking if you can pass both the `$_FILES` and `$_POST` arrays for processing in `go_to_preview.php`, the answer is yes.

The `$_FILES` array is populated when you selected an image via your equip_image element.  Upon posting your form any specified `POST` data in that form will be sent in the headers to `go_to_preview.php`, the `$_FILES` array is sent too, this is seperate from your `$_POST` array.

In your `go_to_preview.php` you can then get the contents of both arrays:

```
$file = $_FILES['equip_image'];
$data = $_POST['form_data'];
```

If you wish to then unset that data you simply call

```
unset($_SESSION['FILES']);
```

Comment: They are then posting the values again to another "final" page and are able to pass the previous `$_POST` using hidden fields but need to also pass `$_FILES`.

Comment: Just seen that an saw your answer, my bad.